# Group user activity by continuous time

Tags: sql-server, grouping

I am trying to group employee activities in a customer account.

Example, in the initial table below

> user1 made 2 changes to the account

> user2 then made 3 changes

> and finally, user1 again made 2 more changes.

*Initial table*

```
time               username 
11:45:53 AM        user1    
11:45:57 AM        user1    
11:52:38 AM        user2    
11:52:38 AM        user2    
11:52:38 AM        user2    
12:47:13 PM        user1    
12:47:13 PM        user1
```

*Goal*

```
time          username   bucket
11:45:53 AM   user1      1
11:45:57 AM   user1      1
11:52:38 AM   user2      2
11:52:38 AM   user2      2
11:52:38 AM   user2      2
12:47:13 PM   user1      3
12:47:13 PM   user1      3
```

I tried `group by`, `lag()` and `lead()`

```
select time, username,  
  lag_username = lag(username, 1) over (partition by username order by time asc),
  lead_username = lead(username, 1) over (partition by username order by time asc)
from x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you can do that by using `lag` to detect when the username changes, and then using `sum` to add to a count every time it changes as follows:

```
declare @Test table (TheTime time, Username varchar(5));

insert into @Test (TheTime, Username)
values ('11:45:53 AM', 'user1'),    
('11:45:57 AM', 'User1'),
('11:52:38 AM', 'User2'),
('11:52:38 AM', 'User2'),
('11:52:38 AM', 'User2'),
('12:47:13 PM', 'User1'),
('12:47:13 PM', 'User1');

with cte1 as (
  select TheTime, Username
    , lag(username) over (order by TheTime) LaggedUsername
  from @Test
), cte2 as (
  select TheTime, Username
    , sum(case when Username = LaggedUsername then 0 else 1 end) over (order by TheTime) Bucket
  from cte1
)
select TheTime, Username, Bucket
from cte2
order by TheTime;
```

Comment: That worked thank you @Dale. I came across "gap and island" but your solution is much simpler.